# Implementing WebDAV ACL: should I modify or replace access entries?

Tags: webdav

Let's suppose I do ACL method on a resource for the first time:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <D:acl xmlns:D="DAV:">
     <D:ace>
       <D:principal>
         <D:href>http://www.example.com/users/esedlar</D:href>
       </D:principal>
       <D:grant>
         <D:privilege><D:write/></D:privilege>
       </D:grant>
     </D:ace>
</D:acl>
```

And then on **the same resource** for a second time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <D:acl xmlns:D="DAV:">
     <D:ace>
       <D:principal>
         <D:href>http://www.example.com/users/esedlar</D:href>
       </D:principal>
       <D:grant>
         <D:privilege><D:read/></D:privilege>
       </D:grant>
     </D:ace>
</D:acl>
```

Should D:write be retained for http://www.example.com/users/esedlar after request #2?

Answer (score 0):

RFC extract: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3744#page-40

> Specifically, the ACL
> method only permits modification to ACEs that are not inherited, and
> are not protected.  An ACL method invocation modifies all non-
> inherited and non-protected ACEs in a resource's access control list
> to exactly match the ACEs contained within in the DAV:acl XML element
> (specified in Section 5.5) of the request body.  An ACL request body
> MUST contain only one DAV:acl XML element.  Unless the non-inherited
> and non-protected ACEs of the DAV:acl property of the resource can be
> updated to be exactly the value specified in the ACL request, the ACL
> request MUST fail.